# Why do I get higher p-values for a better GLM model?

Tags: generalized-linear-model, p-value, residuals

I am modelling an outcome of sport games: whether the first of second team wins (no draws), the variable `who_win`. There are coefficients the bookmaker provides at game start, the smaller the oefficient the larger the probability of a team winning.

$$p(whowin=1) = 1 / coeffcient1$$
$$p(whowin=2) = 1 / coeffcient2$$

Is a basic equation to get the probabilities out of the team coefficients, but their sum are typically greater then 1, beacuse the team coefficients are typically lowered to favor a bookmaker.

**What puzzles me is that** when I use team coefficient as it is in modelling, I get `model_1` with very high z-values (low p-values), but the Residual deviance is worse when compared to a case when I use 1/coefficient as a covariate in `model_2`, where p-values are large enough to say the regressor weights are not different from 0.

**What does this situation indicate?**

```
> model_1 <-
+   glm(
+       who_win ~ start_coef1 + start_coef2
+       , ddt[!is.na(pr1) & !is.na(pr2) & !is.na(start_coef1) & !is.na(start_coef2)]
+       , family = binomial(link = 'logit')
+   ) %>% summary %>% print

Call:
glm(formula = who_win ~ start_coef1 + start_coef2, family = binomial(link = "logit"), 
    data = ddt[!is.na(pr1) & !is.na(pr2) & !is.na(start_coef1) & 
        !is.na(start_coef2)])

Deviance Residuals: 
    Min       1Q   Median       3Q      Max  
-2.8944  -1.0952  -0.3067   1.1571   2.9470  

Coefficients:
            Estimate Std. Error z value Pr(>|z|)    
(Intercept) -0.04451    0.05086  -0.875    0.381    
start_coef1  0.26402    0.01325  19.930   <2e-16 ***
start_coef2 -0.26773    0.01174 -22.795   <2e-16 ***
---
Signif. codes:  0 ‘***’ 0.001 ‘**’ 0.01 ‘*’ 0.05 ‘.’ 0.1 ‘ ’ 1

(Dispersion parameter for binomial family taken to be 1)

    Null deviance: 24256  on 17561  degrees of freedom
Residual deviance: 21249  on 17559  degrees of freedom
AIC: 21255

Number of Fisher Scoring iterations: 5

> 
> model_2 <-
+   glm(
+       who_win ~ I(1 / start_coef1) + I(1 / start_coef2)
+       , ddt[!is.na(pr1) & !is.na(pr2) & !is.na(start_coef1) & !is.na(start_coef2)]
+       , family = binomial(link = 'logit')
+   ) %>% summary %>% print

Call:
glm(formula = who_win ~ I(1/start_coef1) + I(1/start_coef2), 
    family = binomial(link = "logit"), data = ddt[!is.na(pr1) & 
        !is.na(pr2) & !is.na(start_coef1) & !is.na(start_coef2)])

Deviance Residuals: 
    Min       1Q   Median       3Q      Max  
-2.0670  -1.0302  -0.5153   1.0980   2.0957  

Coefficients:
                 Estimate Std. Error z value Pr(>|z|)  
(Intercept)        0.2665     1.3910   0.192   0.8481  
I(1/start_coef1)  -2.4815     1.3363  -1.857   0.0633 .
I(1/start_coef2)   1.9090     1.3348   1.430   0.1527  
---
Signif. codes:  0 ‘***’ 0.001 ‘**’ 0.01 ‘*’ 0.05 ‘.’ 0.1 ‘ ’ 1

(Dispersion parameter for binomial family taken to be 1)

    Null deviance: 24256  on 17561  degrees of freedom
Residual deviance: 21066  on 17559  degrees of freedom
AIC: 21072

Number of Fisher Scoring iterations: 3


plot(model_1)
```

[image]

```
plot(model_2)
```

[image]

**Update**

When I removed an intercept, I got high significance for the weight, but it is not obvious why that helped.

```
> model_3 <-
+   glm(
+       who_win ~ I(1 / start_coef1) + I(1 / start_coef2) - 1
+       , ddt[!is.na(pr1) & !is.na(pr2) & !is.na(start_coef1) & !is.na(start_coef2)]
+       , family = binomial(link = 'logit')
+   ) %>% summary %>% print

Call:
glm(formula = who_win ~ I(1/start_coef1) + I(1/start_coef2) - 
    1, family = binomial(link = "logit"), data = ddt[!is.na(pr1) & 
    !is.na(pr2) & !is.na(start_coef1) & !is.na(start_coef2)])

Deviance Residuals: 
    Min       1Q   Median       3Q      Max  
-2.0677  -1.0299  -0.5152   1.0980   2.0949  

Coefficients:
                 Estimate Std. Error z value Pr(>|z|)    
I(1/start_coef1) -2.22562    0.04531  -49.12   <2e-16 ***
I(1/start_coef2)  2.16456    0.04877   44.39   <2e-16 ***
---
Signif. codes:  0 ‘***’ 0.001 ‘**’ 0.01 ‘*’ 0.05 ‘.’ 0.1 ‘ ’ 1

(Dispersion parameter for binomial family taken to be 1)

    Null deviance: 24346  on 17562  degrees of freedom
Residual deviance: 21066  on 17560  degrees of freedom
AIC: 21070

Number of Fisher Scoring iterations: 3

plot(model_3)
```

[image]

Comment: I'm not sure if there is much to see in this res~leverage plots for a logistic regression. Consider using https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/DHARMa/index.html , see notes in the vignette on diagnosing logistic regressions.

Comment: @FlorianHartig, thank you! I started looking into this pakage functionality.

Answer (score 2):

After I made additional checks and readings, I came to a conclusion that my `model_1` did not suffice to the linearity assumption of an IV and log odds:

[image]

I have considered this model to be badly formulated.

My second `model_2` was right with respect to this assumption:

[image]

But, the complication with this model was quite high correlation between the two IVs, implying multicollinearuty:

```
> cor.test(dt_analyze[, 1/start_coef1], dt_analyze[, 1/start_coef2])

    Pearson's product-moment correlation

data:  dt_analyze[, 1/start_coef1] and dt_analyze[, 1/start_coef2]
t = -2255.8, df = 17560, p-value < 2.2e-16
alternative hypothesis: true correlation is not equal to 0
95 percent confidence interval:
 -0.9983291 -0.9982274
sample estimates:
      cor 
-0.998279
```

In this situation, I removed one "redundant" IV:

```
> summary(model_2)

Call:
glm(formula = who_win ~ I(1/start_coef1), family = binomial(link = "logit"), 
    data = ddt[!is.na(pr1) & !is.na(pr2) & !is.na(start_coef1) & 
        !is.na(start_coef2)])

Deviance Residuals: 
    Min       1Q   Median       3Q      Max  
-2.0611  -1.0298  -0.5121   1.0961   2.1011  

Coefficients:
                 Estimate Std. Error z value Pr(>|z|)    
(Intercept)       2.25496    0.05083   44.37   <2e-16 ***
I(1/start_coef1) -4.38920    0.08851  -49.59   <2e-16 ***
---
Signif. codes:  0 ‘***’ 0.001 ‘**’ 0.01 ‘*’ 0.05 ‘.’ 0.1 ‘ ’ 1

(Dispersion parameter for binomial family taken to be 1)

    Null deviance: 24256  on 17561  degrees of freedom
Residual deviance: 21068  on 17560  degrees of freedom
AIC: 21072

Number of Fisher Scoring iterations: 3
```

The qulity of the model stays good, and the model itself should be good.

**If I missed something please let me kindly know what the flows are.**